# C# Why do arrays have Length and collections have Count?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, count

C# Why do arrays and collections have a difference between the names of the same attribute (Count and Length)?
It just causes headaches to people that are not familiar with this matter.

Comment: There is also `LongLength` for arrays, because they can be multidimensional for example

Comment: Actually, arrays also have a Count property, as arrays also implement the ICollection interface which has a Count property. So if you write a method which would accept an array as input, you should about that instead of accepting just an array T[] maybe accepting ICollection<T> or IList<T> would be better, as it would make your method more versatile by accepting other kinds of collections aside from arrays (arrays as well as List<T> implement both interfaces), with the added benefit that you don’t need to think if Length or Count is correct.

Comment: Arrays have Count "method" not property where list has Count as a property.

Comment: Arrays don't have a Count property or method, LINQ adds a Count extension to arrays...

Comment: @McGuireV10 to be clear, LINQ adds the `Count` extension method to anything that implements `IEnumerable` which includes arrays.

Comment: Don't ask question, why a rose is called a rose and not a horse. It is like it is. It could be called "abc" if the return value is documented.

Answer (score 7):

`Length` generally refers to a fixed size, whereas `Count` generally refers to content which could change. (I say *generally* because there are some exceptions to this, such as an `IReadOnlyList` which isn't going to change, but still has a `Count` since it is based upon a more generalized List interface.)

Answer (score 3):

Besides @McGuireV10's answer part of the reason is historical. C# has it's roots in C, which use the "length" term when talking about arrays and strings. There was no compelling reason to *not* use "length".

Over the years, collections have been refined, genericized, and hold all kinds of different, countable objects, so "count" also makes sense.

I think another part of this is how we talk about our data structures. It is more natural to say, "what is the length of the array" than "what of the count of the array"; the former sounds natural, and the latter is ambiguous (did you mean count of items in the array or *the number of arrays".

Similarly when answering, "how many widgets are in the dictionary"? you are going to express your answer in terms of a count, not a length.

For something like a string, it's not wrong to think of it in terms of both count *and* length:

- This string has (a count of) 40 characters
- This string has a length of 40

Comment: Good points, although I've always thought "size" would have been a more natural choice than "length".

Comment: Size works too, especially when you add in multidemensionality.

Comment: Well, @McGuireV10 this is more of a language matter, but thanks for the clarification. What is System.Linq's count method?

Comment: @אריאלפוקסמן it's an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), the source is here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L12

Comment: I think the key concept in this Q&A is that both count and length are relevant so embrace both!